# Comparing dates does not give me selected date

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

In my wpf app, I've written following code for comparing selected date format.

C# code:

```
class Harvest_Base
{

    public static DateTime storeTime(String date)
    {

        DateTime returnValue = new DateTime();

        if (date == "")
            return returnValue;

            //Time or Date Component Does not Exist
            string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", "yyyy-mm-dd",
               "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", 
               "h:mm tt","hh:mm tt","HH:mm:ss","H:mm","HH:mm","h:mmtt"};
            DateTime result;

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
                returnValue = result;
            else
                returnValue = DateTime.Today;


        return returnValue;

    }
```

The problem here is, when I set breakpoint and check then 'date' object showing mw selected date properly. Format of date is "yyyy-mm-dd". If I select "2013-08-08" then returnValue showing me date as "08-01-2013 00:08:00". It's totally in different format. If we ignore format, then month is wrong. How should I solve this?

Comment: mm is minutes.  Use MM for months.

Comment: You know that `h` is 12h, and `H` is 24h? Because some hours are in 12h format, some in 24h format in your `formats`

Comment: [Obligatory `DateTime` format strings link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I select "2013-08-08" then returnValue showing me date as "08-01-2013 00:08:00"

Because **mm** is minutes where **MM** is months therefore it is converting it to minutes.

this works well

```
string[] formats= {"yyyy-MM-dd"};
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
    returnValue = result;
else
    returnValue = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: +1 To make it clear to the OP, last of the second row is wrong. `mm` instead of `MM`

Comment: Thanks xanatos and No One.